# 403 error in code, but not when using browser

Tags: python, python-requests

Im trying to pull data from this url: https://sbcharts.investing.com/events_charts/us/38.json

I can paste that in Edge or Chrome and i see the return JSON. Looking at the request/response headers from that..i am adding the following to my python code, but despite all this i still get a 403 permission error.  Any help in debugging this would be appreciated

```
from urllib import request

url='https://sbcharts.investing.com/events_charts/us/38.json'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.51',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'*',
    'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy':'cross-origin',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Security-Policy':'upgrade-insecure-requests',
    'Content-Security-Policy':"default-src https: data: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; form-action https:; report-uri",
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Accept':'application/json,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Referrer-Policy':'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
    'Referrer':'http://localhost:5000/'
    }
            
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The response returned from this is 403.  The data in the response seems to be binary or hex..so not readable

```
raw:
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7fd97814c7f0>
reason: 'Forbidden'
request: <PreparedRequest [GET]>
status_code: 403
text:
'\x13�\x11\x00�>��ݹ�z�U\x0eU��$l�!\x06��\x1e�o!���\x0c\x13�{\x13�5�N����)\'��\x12��d۷I�))��\x034�!w\n��S�^cB{|\x1aKD���T:\x01Z���?�o[�1��\x14��\x1686ܺ����A�K�t�����x\x00y��Ϣ�P�\x18p�e\x06�m4�G�!�\x1e��_�=�Hɩ\rQ���R�+G�����<���\x13���H�\x06��\u0605�TNE��&G�\x1c�\x1b\x15\x13�Iԟ�d%�RN\r\r��\x00J����������>55Qpa�Z:\t͘���\x07(_��ZC�\x06&\x02�\n��w�\x14N[�ݿ�LZ9:m�\x1f���@g[[s\x12�:ovȕC|��T��J\x1b/umW�O�t��\x18CLˌS�\n=^��\x05�P��$uJ�׀�WB�XfϢ\x0cf|Y}\x7fA�>4\x1a1&7#�\x14�ö́/?�f����1Ň���\x00[avS�\x7f�\x0e�b�S�JGf��\x0c\x00\x16�OV������\x1e�o�2d�\x0c\x050��\x06��\x08�#p���G�f6%��T�"O�;؛�7���i邾L�\x1ex�g�u\x18\x10��5�%3�n�h%�\x0316<�@�REEM�\x15Y\x06�� U�\x0c��T3�\x10ڄ��\x01sx\t�\x17r��$�˒x��L\x12�\x0f�T"$\x05ñ\\�%�EP�\x14А�\x1e\'&A��H1C?\x0b^\x0b��h�&�\x0c\x08W�WK��G\x03�f�\x08\x13�/:7����D�s�q\\`\x0c=�j�ч�q�l �[�\x17��\x04�f�K�,�/�p�o�(�\x0c=T$���\x03`\x10�� �����:��-��\x04\x0b�J�Ւ{�\x1a�[�СsP�+نI���+�d\x03�>\x1d�|j\x02G�tA��w\x0e�d`�\x0b�\t\x07u%}�J��X���\x12,�`�&YN�Zu�\x1bE��Ef#\x0f*?�t��\t<\x04���R2Y��٪�\'��Ќ���{3�9�...
url: 'https://sbcharts.investing.com/events_charts/us/38.json'
_content:
b'\x13\xa4\x11\x00\xc4>\x9b\xf6\xdd\xb9\x9cz\xb4U\x0eU\x96\xf3$l\xb3!\x06\x97\x90\x1e\xa0o!\xb1\xd2\xc3\x0c\x13\xee\x9b{\x13\xa65\xaeN\x94\xad\xd9\xdd)\'\xa5\xfc\x12\xd0\xecd\xdb\xb7I\x81))\xa0\x84\x034\xe2\x94!w\n\xd4\xc9S\xf2^cB{|\x1aKD\xe9\xde\xd0T:\x01Z\xb1\xe6\xfa?\xe1o[\xc11\xbe\xfc\x14\xf7\xff\x1686\xdc\xba\xb0\x86\x9f\xf2A\xbeK\xb0t\x87\xe0\x8c\xa5\xf2x\x00y\xf9\xeb\xcf\xa2\xc0P\xb3\x18p\xe2e\x06\xc0m4\xdeG\xf6!\xba\x1e\xac\x9a_\xb7=\xdeH\xc9\xa9\rQ\x84\x8c\xa1R\xfe+G\xb6\xec\xa8\xf8\x90\x99<\xdb\xe0\xf1\x13\xfd\xdf\xdbH\xe6\x06\xaf\xf8\xd8\x85\xdeTNE\x8a\xb7&G\xb7\x1c\xa8\x1b\x15\x13\xf1I\xd4\x9f\x91d%\xa2RN\r\r\xb7\xee\x00J\xf9\xc1\xb6\xf4\xf9\xab\xf7\x97\x9f\x9e>55Qpa\xafZ:\t\xcd\x98\xe0\xc3\xe5\x07(_\xc0\x87ZC\xed\x06&\x02\x93\n\xe7\xcew\x9c\x14N[\x9c\xdd\xbf\x97LZ9:m\x90\x1f\xed\xac\xbf@g[[s\x12\xba:ov\xc8\x95C|\xa8\x89T\x9d\xc4J\x1b/umW\xc9O\xadt\xb5\xa4\x18CL\xcb\x8cS\xad\n=^\xe1\xe3\xbf\x05\x9aP\xd3\xeb\xb3$uJ\xd3\xd7\x80\xa5WB\xb7Xf\xcf\xa2\x0cf|Y}\x7fA\xbe>4\x1a1&7#\xcb\x14\xbao\xcd\x84/?\xc...
_content_consumed: True
_next: None
```

Comment: The site is blocking you. The response text is "This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data." So you will probably need to try to get the correct headers and cookies by using `requests.Session` or try using `selenium` and automate a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into this, as it seems like an interesting problem.

The issue I think stems from the fact that this is an HTTP/2 endpoint, not HTTP/1.1, which the `requests` package tries to use.

I simply tried switching library, and used httpx, and it works fine

```py
import httpx

url='https://sbcharts.investing.com/events_charts/us/38.json'
httpx.get(url)
```

I didn't even have to set any header for this to work.

Note, `requests` still doesn't seem to support HTTP/2, hence the need for another library.

Answer (score 0):

`requests` worked for me.

```
import requests
from pprint import pp


url = 'https://sbcharts.investing.com/events_charts/us/38.json'
data = requests.get(url)
print(data.status_code)
pp(data.json(), depth=1)
```

output:

```
200
{'data': [...], 'attr': [...]}
```

Comment: interesting... I guess the endpoint is backed by CloudFlares, so it may also have to do with their DDoS detection. The fact that it didn't work for me or the OP, but then worked with an HTTP/2 call, is puzzling though.

Comment: absolutely. when I print the headers there is `'Server': 'cloudflare'`.

Comment: hmm..could have anything to do w/ me running in container using Docker Desktop?

Comment: i asked this question above because this worked fine before i moved everything to a linux based os from windows.

Comment: what happens if you try `requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection.HAS_IPV6 = False`?